# Why is an open set the union of a countable number of connected components?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

In my complex analysis textbook it states that an open set $U$ has  a countable number of connected components without proving it. I tried to find a proof online but I failed. Can someone explain how the statement above holds true? Any help is apreciated.

Edit: Consider an open set that consists of open disks of radius $1/4$ such that they are located in the complex plane in a manner that each ones center coincides with a point $(x,y):x,y\in \Bbb N$. In this case a connected component is a each disk however is this set of sets countable? From what I saw online a ccountable set is a set such that
each component of it can be related with one natural number different at each time.However if we counnted this nnumber of sets in a way that we "related" each set with center $ (n,0)$ to $ n$  wouldn't the multitude of natural numbers be not enough in order to count the number of open disks that we consider?

Comment: Regarding your edit: You've found an injection (one-to-one function) from the natural numbers to your  set of disks. Just because this injection is not bijective (because it is not onto) does not mean that a bijection does not exist. (Infinite sets are funny that way...Sets can be the same size (cardinality) even though there are bijections from one to a proper subset of the other.)

Comment: For your example, look up the fact that there is a bijection between $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$. For your main question, it follows from the fact that $\mathbb C$ has a countable dense subset, which is called being "separable". You can search with that term.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^2$ is countable, so your example does not work. To show that it is countable: enumerate the integer pairs with the following order: $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)$, etc.

Comment: Concerning your "Edit": the right idea is not to "relate each set with center (n,0) to n" but to use any [bijection $\pi:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) to "relate each set with center (m,n) to f(m,n)".  For your main question, look for instance Corollary 16.1.18  in [this book, p. 468](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RvMhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA468)

Comment: A set $S$ is countable if there is a bijection $S \to \Bbb N$ between $S$ and the set of natural numbers. $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is countable because the [Cantor Pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) is one such bijection.

Comment: Sorry for my misprint some minutes ago about that pairing function, I intended to write $\pi(m,n).$ For the main question answered in that book, you may certainly find it in other books or online, most often for open subsets of $\mathbb R$. Your property holds in a [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space) and [locally connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space) space like an open subset of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, but usually not in more general topological spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second-countable, $U$ is second countable. Thus any open cover of $U$ has a countable subcover. Since $U$ is open, each connected component of $U$ is open in $U$. Since $U$ is covered by
it's connected components, there are countably many that cover $U$. But this cover must actually have all the connected components, since they are nonempty and disjoint.